# Pass the <input> value on the site (parse python)

Tags: python, parsing, python-requests

I want to parse the page (for example https://services.audi.ru/dealer-search/) and pass the value of the city field (on the page called "Поиск по городу или дилеру", see image 1) and switch the display view to the list (see image 2).

[The search box in the city](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su3y6.png)

On the site this field is defined as:

```
<input type="text" id="search" class="filter-item__input" placeholder="Поиск по городу или дилеру">
```

[Switch the map to a list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7VA7.png)

Unfortunately, I'm just starting to learn Python and the Requests library and don't fully understand how to set values directly on the site to get a list of all dealerships.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend you looking into beautifulsoup library.

Answer (score 0):

Each input should have a name attribute

```
<input type="text"   name="userdata">
```

views.py

```
def register(request): 
    username = request.POST['userdata']
```

try not to use this HTML form , use Django in built in  form

Comment: Subhasis, thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately, I didn't find the name tag for this object. Can you tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: To understand: this is not my site. I'm just trying to parse an existing site